# Cannot resolve dependencies in spring boot when creating a new application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Error occurs when creating a new application n try to download n build dependencies for the app. I Cannot resolve dependencies when creating a new spring boot application in intellij. [image]

Resolve dependencies error
Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.50

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.5.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.5.3

Cannot resolve mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26

Cannot resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.3

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.9

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.9

How do i solve these issues. Spring boot 2.5.3

Comment: Tf, am trying to create a new spring boot application and the error is that those depencies cannot be resolve. There is no code just dependency issues

Comment: Please look at other questions on how to ask. This question is completely terrible. Please edit the question, describe in detail what you have done and don't add photos, but copy&paste error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to go to your .m2 folder on your machine depending if you are using windows it should be in
C:/Users/username/.m2 and delete the content of that folder.

Of course, you need to be sure that you have dependencies in your pom.xml that are complaining about, if you do have all dependencies, you can go to the next step.

Go back to your IntelliJ and you can run two maven commands ( clean, install ), you can either run them from the terminal of your IntelliJ, or you can run them from maven UI which is located on the top right side of the IntelliJ, next to database UI.

Answer (score 0):

try this two things
1>  building project from console,if not work.
2> if it is a new project try to create project create project using [spring initilizr](https://start.spring.io/)
second approach is recommended.

Comment: This too didnt work,  after importing the dependencies i still got this error on the build-> sync tab. Resolve dependencies error as before

Comment: If nothing working this is last that you can try, delete /c/users/{username}/.m2 folder completely and try rebuilding project. basically all dependency are stored under .m2 also check permissions of .m2 folder.